# Problem with POST from fronside. Method does not support writable dotted-source fields by default

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I create some dotted source field in my serializer. I did it cause have to display name value of foreign key not pk value. But when I trying to POST from frontend djang throws this : AssertionError at /api/my-api/
The `.create()` method does not support writable dotted-source fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `MySerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on dotted-source serializer fields.

So, when I set `read_only = True` my POST from frontend to request null for every field from dotted-source serializer fields.

This is my serializer:

```
class FcaWorksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fell_form = serializers.CharField(source="fell_form.name" )
    #...
    main_type = serializers.CharField(source="main_type.name")

    class Meta:
        model = FcaWorks
        fields = ('id_fca','wkod', 'main_type','fell_form','fell_type','kind',\
        'sortiment','vol_drew','use_type','fca_res','ed_izm','vol_les','act_name',\
        'obj_type','use_area','indicator','comment','date_report')
```

How I can to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the ***`__init__()`*** method of the serializer to *adjust the serializer condition*

```
class FcaWorksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fell_form = serializers.CharField()
    # ...
    main_type = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = FcaWorks
        fields = ('id_fca', 'wkod', 'main_type', 'fell_form', 'fell_type', 'kind',
                  'sortiment', 'vol_drew', 'use_type', 'fca_res', 'ed_izm', 'vol_les', 'act_name',
                  'obj_type', 'use_area', 'indicator', 'comment', 'date_report')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context['request'].method == 'GET':
            self.fields['fell_form'].source = "fell_form.name"
            self.fields['main_type'].source = "main_type.name"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # here you will get the data
        fell_form = validated_data['fell_form']
        main_type = validated_data['main_type']
```

Comment: Thanks, but  django throws this. `create()` did not return an object instance. So create() didn't return any object.

Comment: Yeah... Its obvious. You have to create FcaWorks object and link to the related model and should return the FcaWorks object from create method

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/), there are multiple ways to deal with ForeignKey relations. You don't have to make your own create method if the Foreignkey relations are not "many-to-many".
In your case you can use one of the following:

- SlugRelatedField
- PrimaryKeyRelatedField

  ```
    class FcaWorksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        fell_form = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name", queryset = ***"""The queryset that fell_form came from"""*** )
        #...
        main_type = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name", queryset = ***"""The queryset main_type came from"""***)

        class Meta:
            model = FcaWorks
            fields = ('id_fca','wkod', 'main_type','fell_form','fell_type','kind',\
            'sortiment','vol_drew','use_type','fca_res','ed_izm','vol_les','act_name',\
            'obj_type','use_area','indicator','comment','date_report')
  ```

Then PrimaryKeyRelated Field usage:

```
 class FcaWorksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        fell_form = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source ="fell_form.name", queryset = ***"""The queryset that fell_form came from"""*** )
        #...
        main_type = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="main_type.name", queryset = ***"""The queryset main_type came from"""***)
```

This has worked for me when I had the same problem, however like previously stated for "Many-to-Many" field you have to explicitly write the create and update methods.